# Is that possible to make `cp -R /dir/ .` be the same as `cp -R /dir .`?

Tags: terminal

I come from Linux. I keep making mistakes when I do `cp -R /dir/ .` instead of `cp -R /dir .`. These two commands are identical in Linux world, but different in MacOS. In `cp` manpage:

```
If the source_file ends in a /, 
the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.
```

Since I always use `Tab` autocomplete the directory name and it always has `/` in the end, I really mean copying the directory, **not** the contents of the directory. I don't always remember to delete the `/` suffix. How do MacOS developers avoid these kind of mistakes? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use homebrew, you can install the `coreutils` package, which provides GNU cp (`gcp`), which behaves the way you are familiar with. Then, you could set

`alias cp=/path/to/homebrew/gcp`

in your profile to prefer that version.